# xlSheetVeryHidden gives run time error

Tags: vba

I am exhausted, really, trying to find a solution. I run Excel 2013. When I physically type a code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = "sheet1" Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Next ws

End Sub
```

and I get to "If not ws.Name...etc", VBA actually gives drop down menus as I go along, which tells me that I am working correctly. BUT, as soon as I run the code (Open the workbook), I get an error 1004, method'visible'...

Believe me I have searched and searched, found one or two slight mods but no joy.

Comment: If the name of your worksheet is `Sheet1` instead of `sheet1` (notice the capital letter difference) this will cause an error because you will be trying to hide all worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that you have only one visible sheet in your workbook at this moment, and it has the name other than *sheet1*.

**Each Excel file must have at least one visible worksheet**. So, if you are trying to hide the only visible sheet with this code:

```
ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

Excel throws an error: *Run-time error '1004': Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed*

---

Note that with your current code a worksheet with the name *Sheet1* will be hidden as well, since your comparison is case sensitive. If you want to ignore letter case you can use the code below:

```
If StrComp(ws.Name, "sheet1", vbTextCompare) Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

Comment: I have again looked at this this morning and after some time found the reason...The code instruction is case sensitive. The worksheet name is in higher case, while the coding is in lower case. I have however taken note of your suggestion...thank you very much.

Comment: Just off the side, I have inserted 4 spaces as per rules to have the code display as it must, but it did not work?

Comment: To make the text formatted as code you need also put at least one empty line between the previous text and this code.